# Can I make this checkbox hide/show an element in the same section but under a different class?

Tags: html, css

complete coding newbie with no formal HTML/CSS education here. I am experimenting with a project and wanted to try and make a list of paragraph elements hidden and expandable.

It is important to note that my ways of modifying the site in question are rather limited. I can only directly modify the **CSS of the page** and the **HTML -in- the <h2 class="label">** (not the class itself).

I have included the pieces of HTML and CSS below. The first toggle correctly hides the "Control me"-text. I was wondering if I could do the same for the div class "value" or the paragraph elements under it. The second piece of CSS is, evidently, not working. I assume this has to do with the placement/relationship of the elements. So, my question is: **is this, at all, possible? If so, how?**

I am aware that this "checkbox hack" is not recommended. With the limitiations I described above, I at least want to try it. Consequently, I would appreciate all help on this topic, if only for the sake of experimentation/knowledge.

My apologies if this is a silly question. Thanks in advance!

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .control-me{
    display: none;          /*this works*/
}
#toggle:checked ~ .value{
    display: none;          /*this does not work*/
}
```

```html
<section class="item references">
  <h2 class="label">
    <label for="toggle">References</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden">
    <div class="control-me">Control me</div>
    </h2>
  <div class="value">
    <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: are you allowed javascript

Comment: Parent selector is *NOT* possible with CSS, can you use javascript ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I have just found out that I can use a plugin to "inject" JavaScript in the header. Would there be a simple script for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .control-me{
    display: none;          /*this works*/
}
#toggle:checked ~ .value{
    display: none;          /*this does not work*/
}
```

```html
<section class="item references">
    <label for="toggle">References</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden">
    <div class="control-me">Control me</div>
  <div class="value">
    <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
  </div>
```

The '~' selector requires that both elements have the same parent and element 1 comes before element 2.

In your first example `#toggle:checked` comes before `.control-me` and the elements are both children of the same parent.

Where as in your second example: `#toggle:check` **does** come before `.value` but **they are not from the same parent**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

EDIT: I have added a snippet with the h2 tag removed, to show that if they shared a parent, the desired effect would be achieved.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I was wondering if i could "reach" .value with another selector. I assume that the overarching section does not count as a shared parent?

Comment: The 'section' element would be a Grandparent of the #toggle input but only a parent of the .value element. If the h2 tag was not wrapping the label and input. Then I think you would reach your desired effect.

Comment: Your explanation and edit have made the problem completely clear for me, thank you! (Unfortunately, in this specific case I cannot alter the HTML in such a way. Good to know that it is impossible to make the checkbox hack work here for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript answer (because you mentioned in a comment that you can use JS)-

Add a class `d-none` in CSS and toggle the class via JavaScript on each click.

Here is a working example-

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("value")[0].classList.toggle("d-none");
});
```

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .control-me{
    display: none;          /*this works*/
}

.d-none{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="item references">
  <h2 class="label">
    <label for="toggle">References</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden">
    <div class="control-me">Control me</div>
    </h2>
  <div class="value">
    <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Edit** : Here is the snippet with script tag in the case there is some problem with inserting scripts externally.

```css
#toggle:checked ~ .control-me{
    display: none;          /*this works*/
}

.d-none{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="item references">
  <h2 class="label">
    <label for="toggle">References</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden" onclick="hide()"/>
    <div class="control-me">Control me</div>
    </h2>
  <div class="value">
    <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  function hide(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("value")[0].classList.toggle("d-none");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have made the suggested modifications in the CSS and added the script in the header. Sadly, nothing seems to happen to the paragraphs when I click the checkbox. I think there is not necessarily something wrong with the script, but rather with the way I inserted it. The system I am working in seems to heavily limit these kinds of modifications. Lots of thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: You are inserting the script in the `head` tag. In the case the DOM has not loaded completely, the script would fail to make changes in the DOM. Try inserting the script tag after your content in the `body` tag as demonstrated in the edit.

Comment: @KingRamuh have you done the suggested editing? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: I wish I could do the suggested edits, but unfortunately I cannot directly alter the HTML of the page. I can only change the contents under the <h2 class="label">. I am not sure in which tag I am inserting the script. I just pasted it in the header, as described with this plugin: https://pkp.sfu.ca/2018/03/01/enriching-ojs-omp-with-javascript-no-coding-required/

Comment: I wish I could help you more, but I am unfamiliar with the system/software you are working with. Anyway, nice to help you :D.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have wrapped the `control-me` class inside a `<h2>` tag. Where as the `.value` class is outside the `h2 tag` so it changes only elements inside `<label>`.
Solution No 1:
Put the  outside h2 tag.It works

```
<section class="item references">
      <h2>
        <label for="toggle">References</label>
      </h2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden" />
      <div class="control-me">Control me</div>
      <div class="value">
        <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Solution No 2:
Wrap the things you want to hide inside `h2 tag`

```
<section class="item references">
      <h2>
        <label for="toggle">References</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden" />
        <div class="control-me">Control me</div>

        <div class="value">
          <p>Originally lots of different paragraph elements here</p>
        </div>
      </h2>
    </section>
```